# Call a class attribute of a class instance from a function in python

Tags: python, function, class, matplotlib

Let's say I want to plot different class objects attribute from a function.

So far I have this:

```py
...

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot2vars (deviceList, xVars, yVars, xLims, yLims, colormap=plt.cm.Spectral):
    x0 = xVars[0]
    x1 = xVars[1]
    y0 = yVars[0]
    y1 = yVars[1]
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)
    for d in deviceList: #these 'd' are the class instances...
        if not d.discard:
                    ax[0].plot(d.x0, d.y0)
                    ax[0].set_xlim(xLims[0])
                    ax[0].set_ylim(yLims[0])

                    ax[1].plot(d.x1, d.y1)
                    ax[1].set_xlim(xLims[1])
                    ax[1].set_ylim(yLims[1])
    plt.show()
```

where deviceList is a list containing class instances with different attributes like, for example, `u`, `z` or `T`.

Now, when I call the function, I declare xVars, yVars, xLims, yLims as arrays of strings, which obviously doesn't work. But I don't know how to call these. And I don't even know how to look for this in the manuals...

```py
plot2vars (
      deviceList, 
      xVars=['u', 'u'], yVars=['z', 'T'],  
      xLims=['', 'left=0.8'], yLims=['','bottom=0, top=0.8']
      )
```

Comment: You say it doesn't work. Could you please share the error you're getting? Also, please share an example of a call to this function (the values of all the parameters, including `deviceList`)

Comment: i wrote it in the question, deviceList is a list of Device class instances, which is a class with many attributes, like for example u, z, or T.

Comment: Your function takes `xVars` and `yVars` but never uses them. Is it okay?

Comment: You've edited the question... But still you take `x0, y0 ...` from `xVars` and `yVars` but you don't use them below.

Comment: That is my problem, when I call `d.x0`, python complains there is not x0 attribute of the class, and of course there isn't. I want to call `d.u` instead. And I want to be able to call different attributes everytime I call the function. That's why I need it to be a variable. But I don't know how to.

Comment: Yes, I do use them, when I call the plot function, d.x0, d.y0, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, if you want to take the attributes given as strings from your `xVars` and `yVars`, you should use `getattr` method like this:

```
d.x0 -> getattr(d, x0)
```

For example, if `x0 = 'qwerty'`, `getattr(d, x0)` equals to `d.qwerty`.

So in your code you should use:

```
...
ax[0].plot(getattr(d, x0), getattr(d, y0))
...
ax[1].plot(getattr(d, x1), getattr(d, y1))
...
```

Documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr

---

As for `xLims` and `yLims`, I would define it as list of dictionaries like this:

```
xLims = [{}, {'left': 0.8}]
yLims = [{}, {'bottom': 0, 'top': 0.8}]
```

So this would allow me to use them through `**kwargs` approach:

```
...
ax[0].set_xlim(**xLims[0])
ax[0].set_ylim(**yLims[0])
...
ax[1].set_xlim(**xLims[1])
ax[1].set_ylim(**yLims[1])
...
```

The main idea is when you pass a dictionary to a function with `**` the key-values pairs will be unpacked into key-value arguments.

Comment: Yes! that was exactly what I was asking for. You say 'if I want to take them given as strings', is there any other way? I ask this because, when I call the xLims and yLims in the function, it doesn't recognise them as arrays but of corse as strings...

Comment: I am not sure about other ways. It is a standard way to access an attribute of an object by its name from a variable.

Comment: This works for the class attribute, but not for the xLims given to the set_xlim function... is there a proper way to do this too?

Comment: As far as I can see, it should work in the was you implemented. I can't see any error in it.

Comment: Same here, but this is the error I get: ```File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 2769, in set_xlim
left, right = left
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)```

Comment: Yeah, that’s exactly what I wanted! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand correctly, you are trying to access the attribute `u` of object `d` which would typically be called by writing `d.u`, but you want to be able to do that without defining ahead of time that the attribute in question is `u`.

`d.x0` will look for an attribute of `d` which is called `x0`, which has nothing to do the `x0` you have defined.

The closest thing to what you're trying to do in this case is the `getattr` function: `getattr(d, x0)` should give you what you want.

That being said, it's not great practice if you can avoid using it. I would recommend simply passing `d.u` as argument to `plot2vars` and edit `plot2vars` accordingly when possible.

Comment: The problem is I don't see how I would do that, since d is how I call each class instance inside a loop...

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't meaning to say that you specifically shouldn't use it in this case. I would say it's justified here. I was just giving a general warning. If you wanted to avoid using `getattr` in this case, you could always resort to a list comprehension: call `plot2vars([d.u, d.z, d.u, d.T for d in deviceList], xLims, yLims)` and in `plot2vars` you do `for x0, y0, x1, y1 in first_argument:` and use them directly. Honestly I would say it's better to have a little ugliness hidden away in a function than on display when calling it.

Comment: Oh yes, now I see what you meant! And yes, I agree the function call is more elegant this way.... I would like to accept both answers now :)